# How to use python/PHP to remove redundancy in URL link?

Tags: php, python, html, url, web

Many website add tags to url link for tracking purpose, such as

http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/answer-sheet/post/report-we-still-dont-know-much-about-charter-schools/2012/01/13/gIQAxMIeyP_blog.html?wprss=linkset&tid=sm_twitter_washingtonpost

If we remove the appendix "?wprss=linkset&tid=sm_twitter_washingtonpost", would still go to same page.
Is there any general approach could remove those redundancy element? Any comment would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### To remove query, fragment parts from URL

In Python using [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse#urlparse.urlsplit):

```
import urlparse
 
url = urlparse.urlsplit(URL)               # parse url
print urlparse.urlunsplit(url[:3]+('','')) # remove query, fragment parts
```

Or a more lightweight approach but it might be less universal:

```
print URL.partition('?')[0]
```

According to [rfc 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) URI can be parsed using the regular expression:

```
/^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?/
```

Therefore if there is no fragment identifier (the last part in the above regex) or the query component is present (the 2nd to last part) then `URL.partition('?')[0]` should work, otherwise answers that split an url on '?' would fail e.g.,

```
http://example.com/path#here-?-ereh
```

but `urlparse` answer still [works](http://ideone.com/HhdEt).

#### To check whether you can access page via URL

In Python:

```
import urllib2

try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
except IOError, e:
    print "error: can't open %s, reason: %s" % (URL, e)
else:
    print "success, status code: %s, info:\n%s" % (resp.code, resp.info()),
```

`resp.read()` could be used to read the contents of the page.

Answer (score 1):

**To remove query string in URL :**

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/answer-sheet/post/report-we-still-dont-know-much-about-charter-schools/2012/01/13/gIQAxMIeyP_blog.html?wprss=linkset&tid=sm_twitter_washingtonpost';
$url = explode('?',$url);
$url = $url[0];

//check output
echo $url;
?>
```

**To check URL valid or not:**

You can use PHP function **`get_headers($url)`**. Example:

```
<?php
//$url_o = 'http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/answer-sheet/post/report-we-still-dont-know-much-about-charter-schools/2012/01/13/gIQAxMIeyP_blog.html?wprss=linkset&tid=sm_twitter_washingtonpost';

$url_o = 'http://mobile.nytimes.com/article?a=893626&f=21';

$url = explode('?',$url_o);

$url = $url[0];

$header = get_headers($url);

if(strpos($header[0],'Not Found'))
{
    $url = $url_o;
}

//check output
echo $url; 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Zulkhaery. Some times those '?' tags are necessary. Such as " http://mobile.nytimes.com/article?a=893626&f=21 ". If you remove it, it will not point to the right page. My question is how to know whether it's redundant. Thanks

Comment: @user1063294: Updated my answer to check URL valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a URL parser that will cut everything from "?" and on

```
<?php
$pos = strpos($yourUrl, '?'); //First, find the index of "?"

//Then, cut all the chars after the "?" and a append to a new URL string://
$newUrl = substr($yourUrl, 0, -1*(strlen($yourUrl)-((int)$pos)));

echo ($newUrl);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
$yourUrl = preg_replace("/[?].*/","",$yourUrl);
```

Which meanss: "replace the question mark and everything afterwards with an empty string".

Comment: Thank you Erel. See my comments above.